# ordering in JPA not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa

i'm using JPA with Hibernate implementation.  I've a named query like in an entity MyTable :

```
@NamedQuery(name = "myQuery", query = "select val from MyTable val")
```

The myTable entity is containing a foriegn key relation with another entity.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "myTable ", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<ReferenceTable> tbl;
```

There is a field in the ReferenceTable entity, that i need to get in sorted order when JPA runs the named query shown above.  I tried @OrderBy but that didnt work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
nks

Comment: If you want some field in a sorted order, then you make the java type of that field something that supports ordering ... like a List. No needing of reading the JPA spec for that, just common sense around java.util collections

Comment: Hm, you might want to get an update of your java.util.collection "common sense". Try by starting with SortedSet... JPA doesn't support SortedSet, but EclipseLink for instance will accept an implementation of SortedSet (like TreeSet) with a default constructor. It will require the FetchType to be EAGER though, even if the OrderBy is provided. And of course the class will have to implement the Comparable interface...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently @OrderBy doesn't work well with Hibernate's JPA implementation:

http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/index.html#entity-mapping-association-collections

Is that what you're using?

At any rate, try adding the "order by" in your JPQL query, something like

select ... order by tbl DESC

Also, if you want complete flexibility, make a native sql query, where you select your stuff and order it per your liking. You can even tell your native query to what class's it should marshall the results, so you get pretty much the same thing that a JPQL query would get you,  but with more precision on the actual query:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
```

name="myQuery",
query="SELECT .... order by ... asc"
resultClass=MyJPAEntity.class
)

You can but the above as a class level annotation on your entity bean class.

And yes, i do get the irony of using an orm framework but still being forced to rever to basic sql.

Answer (score 0):

Set<..> impl will be undordered even if DB/JPA returns an ordered collection. you can use SortedSet as shown in this example from hibernate documentation

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="CUST_ID")
@Sort(type = SortType.COMPARATOR, comparator = TicketComparator.class)
public SortedSet<Ticket> getTickets() {
    return tickets;
}
```

source : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-sorted

Comment: Is that true?? So you have a 100k$ database (if it's Oracle), doing miracles with sorting, just to sort things again in Java? (I'm not criticising your answer, I just can't believe Hibernate should work this way)

Comment: Yeah but that's not really true JPA, it's mixed with Hibernate specific stuff (Sort annotation). Besides, Sort annot. does the sorting in memory, it doesn't take advantage of the database's sorting capabilities. OrderBy annot. implies just that - that you'll do the sorting at the database.

Comment: @LukasEder: +1 that's very true.

Comment: @AndreiBodnarescu, ah OK so that exists, too. But you say it doesn't work well...

Comment: @Lukas I wondered too but I see this in documentation `If you want the database itself to order the collection elements, use the order-by attribute of set, bag or map mappings. This solution is implemented using LinkedHashSet or LinkedHashMap and performs the ordering in the SQL query and not in the memory.`, but i guess that's not working for user957183

Comment: @kunal: it's really a hibernate bug that they won't admit. The OrderBy annotation should behave just like you say in the quote from your comment there, but in Hibernate's JPA impementation it simply doesn't. But it's better PR-ing to say "our implementation bla bla, use etc etc " than simply saying "the specs say this, but our implementation doesn't respect them" :P

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use org.hibernate.annotations.Sort which sorts in Java using a comparator, you are better off without java.util.Set. Using set won't help you with ordering (the best thing Hibernate could pick here would be a LinkedHashSet). I also doubt you use it to make sure an element is unique.

I think you'd better use java.util.Collection which is the most generic. Hibernate uses ArrayList as default, which will keep the result set's order. However, Hibernate's implementation of @OrderBy is bad, it doesn't seem to fully implement JPA 2.0, not in 4.1.9 either. This might also be why you have troubles.

Comment: Do you know if t his is still the case with the current version 4.3.2? If yes, which ORM does a better job regarding this issue?

Comment: I hope someone else replies, as I'm not working in that company anymore and I'm not doing any Java EE development at the moment.